# Language benchmark page from debian/alioth

Tags: benchmarking

Where are the famous benchmark pages on debian.org? They use to be at http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/ but it moved to
http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/ now it is gone. Does anyone know where it went?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a resource.

Comment: The machine hosting the storage for alioth.debian.org suffered catastrophic disk failure. http://lists.debian.org/debian-infrastructure-announce/2013/11/msg00001.html

Comment: @igouy: Thanks! I'm glad to hear it isn't going down permanently.

Comment: The benchmarks game website is now available again.

Comment: with reduced functionality

Comment: I don't quite understand why they stripped off the functionality of the page... used to be extremely informative, now it's difficult to navigate and lacking information.

Comment: It's soooooooo bad now compared to what it used to be.  So sad.  I wonder if the raw data is available?

Comment: @astrojuanlu : see https://alioth.debian.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=14962&forum_id=2965&group_id=100815

Comment: @William Stein : Your question is answered on the website (twice) see http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/play.html or http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/how-programs-are-measured.html